# How to compress old log files when reached MaxBackupIndex size?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

We have a specific requirement needed for our customer's application server.We are on JBoss server and using log4j for log roll up. 
The log files at customer site are rolled up in 1 or 2 days. We are maintaining only 20 log files as 'MaxBackupIndex'.Once this limit is reached the old log files are slipped.
The following **Configuration** in jboss-log4j.xml file is used.

`<appender name="FILEAPPENDER" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/../../../../logs/JBServer.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20"/>`

```
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
 </layout>
```

We would like to compress the old log files to .gz file whenever the MaxBackupIndex is reached and try to create a new log file. 
How can we do that ? Help would be appreciated. 

Thanks,
Rama Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement and we had to change the RollingFileAppender code for that. Or you can create your own appender (Extend to to RollingFileAppender) and change the *void rollOver()* method the way you want it to work.

Also if you have liberty to use the logback framework then go for it. It is very easy to configure such things in logback.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I will try that out.